# Whats the relation between window and app in pyqt?

Tags: python, pyqt

Every pyqt beginners tutorial starts with something like this:
`
import sys

```
import sys

from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QWidget,
)

app = QApplication([])

window = QWidget()
window.setWindowTitle("test")
window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

My question is: I dont see at any point where "window" is assigned to "app", so, how does "app" know about "window"?

Even in books I did not find an explanation.

Comment: A widget that is created without any parent is considered a top level window (until it's reparented, for example when added to a layout).

Comment: and how does app know about this top level window? Does QWidget at __init__ somehow register itself to QApplication or something like that?

Comment: @user2489139 Yes, it does, by doing two steps: 1. check if a QApplication instance actually exists (which is mandatory for QWidget creation, and there can only be *one* Qt application instance running); 2. add itself to the "all widget" list, which is a unique list of all existing widgets, and to which QApplication can access (through `QApplication.allWidgets()`).